# How to crop an image to a specific height and width?

Tags: jquery, cropperjs

Why am I not getting an image of specific height and width?

Suppose I set the crop image to width=308 & height=200, it returns 308 X 308.
If I set width=200 & height=308, it returns 308 x 308. It is returning the maximum size from height and width. How do I fix this problem?

I am using cropper.js

```
if (cropper) {
    canvas = cropper.getCroppedCanvas({
        width: 308, // here set  width 
        height: 200, // here set height 
        imageSmoothingEnabled: false,
        imageSmoothingQuality: 'high',
        fillColor: '#fff',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set aspectRatio free as below code:

```
if (cropper) {
    canvas = cropper.getCroppedCanvas({
    width: 308, // here set  width 
    height: 200, // here set height
     aspectRatio: "free", // or Free or 0
    imageSmoothingEnabled: false,
    imageSmoothingQuality: 'high',
    fillColor: '#fff',
});
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: Not working ! when I cropped image height =200 but width changed everytime sometime 163 or 157 but not fixed width 308 Thank you  for replied